# Laravel Images uploaded are not showing but link storage is working

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

I'm currently uploading 2 projects into my ubuntu server with cyberpanel. (One of them is https://simplycar.es/storage/fotos/1677542768-WhatsApp%20Image%202023-02-28%20at%2001.03.28.jpeg)

Both are in Laravel and use the same way to upload images.

Way to upload:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($request->file('foto'))) {
        $picture = time() . "-" . $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('foto')->storeAs('public/fotos', $picture);
    }
```

I already have another project running with the same structure to upload pictures, and it works correctly (https://chaincapitals.com/storage/logos/1669744070-C5l3mHJg_400x400.png).

But these two new projects don't work with the uploaded images. They don't appear in the URL (app. URL/(image-name)) and they don't show on the website.

I'm writing the route of the images as I always do it:

```
{{asset('storage/fotos/'. \App\Models\Image::where('idCar' , $car->id)->first()->imagen)}}
```

The storage link is working because, in my FTP App, it appears.

I tried to regenerate the symlink also generate it from a .PHP file.

Also, I tried with permissions things, I try this two things:

```
chmod -R o+w storage
chmod -R o+w bootstrap/cache
```

Also, I triod some other commands I saw on other topics.

Comment: "they don't appear on the website" - what does that mean? Do these files get uploaded to the folder?

Comment: @NicoHaase , yes they got uploaded to the folder, but "they don't appear on the website" I'm referring to they don't show them, such as they don't exist on that route.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is the route generated properly?

Comment: How does the generated URL look like? How should it look like? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I put some urls on the post, I also wrote the 3 things I tried to fix it, because it was all I could find in other topics and I don't really know what is happening as I have other project with the same structure in the same server and its working.

Comment: Please share more details. How would the **correct** URL look like, compared to the **currently generated** URL? Also, is this really a problem related to Apache or Ubuntu?

Comment: Setting other permissions does not change how the URL is generated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, certainly. As a wild guess, check your permission since you say it worked on another project.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/
sudo chmod -R 775 storage/

# finally 
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of @Abdula Nilam I got the following error:

> The stream or file "/home/simplycar.es/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream:

I assume is because of permissions of the storage folder.

I fixed it with:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage
```

After this I got my app working correctly.